# A union of open sets is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have read the proof:
[image]
Form [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~taipale/hmwk1.5.pdf)

What I do not fully understand is:

what does $B_{r}(x)$ means? what I have learned is that an open ball is  a set of all x's hows there norm ("distance") from the center (namley a point $a$) is less then the radius $r$ which denoted as $B(a,r)=||x-a||<r$, in the case of $B_{r}(x)$ what is the center point?

Comment: It is a different notation of the same thing $B_r(x)$ is the same as $B(x,r)$

Comment: r is the radius and x the center.

Comment: @marwalix so in $B_{r}(x)$ we denote $r$ to be the radius, $x$ to be any point that $||x-c||<r$ where $c$ is the center of the ball? meaning that in this notation we do not explicitly write which point is the center?

Comment: @gbox, $x$ is the center. $B_r(x)=\left\{ y: \left\| y-x\right\| <r \right\}$

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh so the proof is a bit confusing as we take a general point $x$ and then denote it to be the center of an open ball?

Comment: Or because it is a norm (absolute value) it does not matter if $x$ is a center or not, it just need to be in the open ball?

Comment: $B_r (a)=B (a,r) $ and $B_r (x)=B (x,r) $.  The center point is whatever you say it is.  In your definition you labeled it as $a $ and then you referred to all the other points with the variable $x$.  But a and x are just labels.  With $B_r (x) $ this text labels the center with the label $x $ and refers to the other (unspecified) points with another unfixed variable.  Possibly $y $ or something else.  It doesn't matter as they are just labels.

Comment: The text has another notation than you use, but it also has another variable convention than you use.  You seem to use $a $ or "low" variables to indicate a known point and use $x $ for general points in the neighbor hood.  These text uses the variable $x $ as the known point.  But these are conventions.  They are just labels.  $B(a,r) $ are all points within $r $ of point $a $.  $B_h (x) $ are all points within $h $ of point $x $.  They are the same definition.  The just use different notation and labels.

Comment: If you like, you can replace every occurrence in you text of $x $ to $a $.  It won't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

$B_r(x)$ means ball of radius $r$ with center at $x$.

Explaination of the proof:

One way to show that a set $S$ is open is to show that whenever we take a point $x \in S$, we can construct a ball centered at $x$ such that this ball is a subset of $S$.

For simplicity, let's just look at special case of union of two open sets $A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are both open.

Let me pick any $x$ from $A \cup B$.

Our goal would be to construct an open ball with $x$ being the center such that $B_r(x) \subset A \cup B$.

By definition of union. $x$ belongs to $A$ or $x$ belongs to $B$.

WLOG, we can assume $x$ belongs to $A$, since $A$ is open, we can construct a ball around $x$ ($x$ is the center), $B_r(x)=\left\{ y: \left\| x-y\right\|<r\right\} \subset A$. Clearly, we have $B_r(x) \subset A \cup B$.

Hence we have shown that it $A \cup B$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

In $B_r(x)$, $r$ denotes the radius of the open ball around the point $x$.